# Memory allocation problems with arrays in structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am relatively new to c and have a tricky problem, 
I have tracked it down to a memory allocation problem (see code below) but do not understand why the compiler is doing this and would like to know how to do it right. I am running this on gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4).
The code below should compile stand alone, at least it does on my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


  #define MAXCOL       100   
  typedef enum {
    DL,                
    DLIMEPS            
  } omodel_type;       

  typedef  double *   pcn_type;  
  struct drd_osc_type{
    pcn_type aaa;      
    pcn_type ggg;      
    pcn_type ooo;      
    pcn_type ddd;      
    omodel_type omodel;
    double beps;       
    double egap;       
    int no;            
  };
  typedef struct drd_osc_type * pdrd_osc;


//=====================================================================
unsigned long int  address_int(void * ccc){
  char *s=malloc(100);
  sprintf(s,"%p", ccc);
  int x;
  sscanf(s,"%x",&x);
  return x;
}

//=====================================================================

pdrd_osc   ini_drdosc(){
  pdrd_osc  ccc;

  if ( (ccc=malloc(sizeof(pdrd_osc)))==NULL){
       perror("malloc 3");
    printf("ini_drdosc :malloc failed\n");
       return NULL;
   }
  ccc->omodel=DL;
  ccc->no=0;
  ccc->beps=1;
  ccc->egap=0;
  ccc->aaa=malloc(100*sizeof(double));
  ccc->ggg=malloc(100*sizeof(double));
  ccc->ooo=malloc(100*sizeof(double));
  ccc->ddd=malloc(100*sizeof(double));
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<MAXCOL;i++)ccc->aaa[i]=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<MAXCOL;i++)ccc->ggg[i]=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<MAXCOL;i++)ccc->ooo[i]=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<MAXCOL;i++)ccc->ddd[i]=0.0;
  //printf("Hello\n");
  printf(" SIZE OF ccc             : %i\n", (int) sizeof(pdrd_osc)); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc             : %p\n",  ccc); 
  printf(" ADDRESS (INT) ccc       : %lu\n",  address_int(ccc)); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.omodel      : %lu\n", address_int( &(ccc->omodel))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.no          : %lu\n",     address_int( &( ccc->no))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.beps        : %lu\n",   address_int( &( ccc->beps))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.egap        : %lu\n",   address_int( &( ccc->egap))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.aaa         : %lu\n",    address_int( &(ccc->aaa))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.aaa[0]      : %lu\n",    address_int( &(ccc->aaa[0]))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.aaa[maxcol] : %lu\n",    address_int( &(ccc->aaa[MAXCOL]))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.ggg         : %lu\n",    address_int(&( ccc->ggg))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.ooo         : %lu\n",    address_int(&( ccc->ooo))); 
  printf(" ADDRESS ccc.ddd         : %lu\n",    address_int(&( ccc->ddd))); 
  return ccc;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
pdrd_osc drdosc;drdosc=(pdrd_osc) ini_drdosc();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it I get the following result:

```
 SIZE OF ccc             : 8
 ADDRESS ccc             : 0x1086010
 ADDRESS (INT) ccc       : 17326096
 ADDRESS ccc.omodel      : 17326128
 ADDRESS ccc.no          : 17326152
 ADDRESS ccc.beps        : 17326136
 ADDRESS ccc.egap        : 17326144
 ADDRESS ccc.aaa         : 17326096
 ADDRESS ccc.aaa[0]      : 17326128
 ADDRESS ccc.aaa[maxcol] : 17326928
 ADDRESS ccc.ggg         : 17326104
 ADDRESS ccc.ooo         : 17326112
 ADDRESS ccc.ddd         : 17326120
```

So the first `malloc` in the function `ini_drdosc`reserves in memory 8 bytes, which is fine. However, the address space reserved by this `malloc` for the variables `omodel,no,beps`,and `egap` is overwritten by the next `malloc` for the (fixed size array) `aaa`, as the printout of the addresses of `aaa[0]` and `aaa[maxcol]` demonstrates. Why? How to make the compiler protect the variables `omodel,no,beps`,and `egap` in order to avoid segfaults etc.?

I am really completely stuck here and would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the sizeof a pointer-type not the struct itself. Depending on 64/32bit system this will be 8 and 4 byte repectively.

```
ccc=malloc(sizeof(drd_osc_type)));
```

Should allocate the correct size.

Comment: Or something like `sizeof(*pdrd_osc)`.

Comment: OK, great thanks. Stupid mistake on my part. You get so blind when staring on subtley incorrect code, especially of course in c with all the ampersands and asterisks etc. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your help!!!! I really appreciate it. The following changes did the trick
      `typedef struct drd_osc_type drd_osc;` 
      `typedef drd_osc * pdrd_osc;`      `if ( (ccc=malloc(sizeof(drd_osc)))==NULL){ etc..`